# Completeness of a basis

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, fourier-series, inner-products

In the space of continuous functions on $C([0,2\pi]),$ how does one go about showing that the functions ${1\over\sqrt{2\pi}},$ ${1\over\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx)$ and ${1\over\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx)$ form a complete orthonormal system? The orthonormality is rather easy to check given that the inner product is defined by: $\langle a,b \rangle=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} a(x) b(x)  dx.$ But how about the verification of the completeness?

Is it an idea to try and show that the sum of the normalized basis functions above is equal to the identity operator?

Comment: The sum of normalized basis functions would not be the identity operator, since it won't be an operator at all, but a vector in $C[0, 2\pi]$. Furthemore, this sum even isn't defined, since it diverges. Probably, you mean prooving that $I=\sum |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|$, where $\{e_i\}$ is the basis.

Comment: @lisyarus exactly, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). It states that an unital algebra $A$ of functions is dense in the space of all real-valued functions on an interval, iff it separates points. The last property means that $\forall x,y \in [0,2\pi] \quad \exists f \in A \quad f(x) \neq f(y)$. Take $A$ to be the set of *finite* linear combinations of elements of your basis, and

1. Prove that it is indeed an algebra (closed under multiplication - this follows from trigonometric formulas)
2. Prove that it separates points (this is easy - $\sin x$ already *almost* separates all of them).

By Stone-Weierstrass, this algebra is dense, which means that *infinite* sums of it's elements span the whole space.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that this basis is the eigenbasis of Laplacian, or provides decomposition into irreducible representations of $SO(2)$, which are all known to be orthonormal and complete under suitable conditions (however, as far as I know, general proofs of this use Stone-Weierstrass anyway).